# How to Preload the below image that is wrapped inside an anchor(<a></a>) tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, performance, preload

I have tried giving rel="preload" for the anchor tag but still it is not working. I need the image that is wrapped inside the div which is already inside anchor tag should be preloaded so that it will improve the page performance.

```
<a
  key={index}
  href={ '/image/url/' }
  title={item.image.altText}
  target={item?.link?.target}
>
  <div
    key={index}
  >
    <img
      src={item.image}
      alt={item.image && item.image.altText}
    />
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't see how this `<a>` changes anything here

Comment: You can either set the [fetchPriority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchPriority) to high or add a [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) link to the `<head>`